Buttons not working in the blazor webapp in Visual Studio 2022
I have a blazor app in the Visual Studio 2022. In it I have a todo list page in the nav menu.
This is the TodoItem.cs:
 [Table ("todo")]
 public class ToDoItem
 {
     
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     [Column("id")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Column ("name")]
     [MaxLength(100)]
     public string? Name { get; set; }
     [Column("detail")]
     [MaxLength(100)]
     public string? Detail { get; set; }
     [Column("status")]
     public bool Status { get; set; }
 }

I have it connected to a docker and sql server management database.
This is the ToDoService.cs:
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public ToDoService(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<ToDoItem> GetToDoItems()
    {
        return _context.ToDoItems.ToList();
    }

    public void AddToDoItem(ToDoItem item)
    {
        _context.ToDoItems.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void RemoveToDoItem(int id)
    {
        var item = _context.ToDoItems.Find(id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            _context.ToDoItems.Remove(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateToDoItem(ToDoItem updatedItem)
    {
        var existingItem = _context.ToDoItems.Find(updatedItem.Id);
        if (existingItem != null)
        {
            existingItem.Name = updatedItem.Name;
            existingItem.Detail = updatedItem.Detail;
            existingItem.Status = updatedItem.Status;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

This is the TodoList.razor component:
@page "/todolist"
@using Quest1.Entities
@using Quest1.Model
@using Quest1.Service
@inject ToDoService ToDoService

<h3>To-Do List</h3>

<div class="add-todo">
    <input @bind="newToDoItem.Name" placeholder="Enter name" />
    <input @bind="newToDoItem.Detail" placeholder="Enter detail" />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" @bind="newToDoItem.Status" />
        Completed
    </label>
    <button @onclick="AddToDoItem">Add</button>
</div>

@if (toDoItems != null && toDoItems.Count > 0)
{
    <ul class="todo-list">
        @foreach (var item in toDoItems)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="todo-item">
                    <div class="todo-item-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" @bind="item.Status" />
                        <span>@item.Name</span>
                        <span>@item.Detail</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="todo-item-actions">
                        <button class="edit-button" @onclick="() => EditToDoItem(item)">Edit</button>
                        <button class="remove-button" @onclick="() => RemoveToDoItem(item.Id)">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <p>No to-do items available.</p>
}

@if (editMode)
{
    <div class="edit-todo">
        <input @bind="editedToDoItem.Name" placeholder="Enter name" />
        <input @bind="editedToDoItem.Detail" placeholder="Enter detail" />
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="editedToDoItem.Status" />
            Completed
        </label>
        <button @onclick="UpdateToDoItem">Save</button>
        <button @onclick="CancelEdit">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private List<ToDoItem> toDoItems;
    private ToDoItem newToDoItem = new ToDoItem();
    private ToDoItem editedToDoItem = new ToDoItem();
    private bool editMode = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LoadToDoItems();
    }

    private void LoadToDoItems()
    {
        toDoItems = ToDoService.GetToDoItems();
    }

    private void AddToDoItem()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newToDoItem.Name))
        {
            ToDoService.AddToDoItem(newToDoItem);
            newToDoItem = new ToDoItem();
            LoadToDoItems();
        }
    }

    private void EditToDoItem(ToDoItem item)
    {
        editedToDoItem = item;
        editMode = true;
    }

    private void UpdateToDoItem()
    {
        ToDoService.UpdateToDoItem(editedToDoItem);
        editedToDoItem = new ToDoItem();
        editMode = false;
        LoadToDoItems();
    }

    private void CancelEdit()
    {
        editedToDoItem = new ToDoItem();
        editMode = false;
    }

    private void RemoveToDoItem(int id)
    {
        ToDoService.RemoveToDoItem(id);
        LoadToDoItems();
    }
}

And it's connected with this in the AppDbContext:
 public DbSet<ToDoItem> ToDoItems { get; set; }
The Page itself looks like this:enter image description here
When I was using **Add-Migration ** and Update-Database. It was bit clunky since I still could not see the table todo in the Database itself.
But when I used a query to import data(Garden,Watering plants,1)  to the table. It did show up. As seen in the picture.
Buttons Add, Edit, Remove do not work.
Why?
-ps
I'm sorry for perhaps being unclear. I am very new to all of this and I a bit of rush.
Thanks in advance.
